Can time dilation between two clocks be communicated at a distance?
There are many questions on stack exchange related to time dilation, and I think this answer gets closest to answering my question, but not quite (or at least not in a way that it is clear to me). I have read through many SE Q/A's on the subject and have not found an answer to the following:

If two clocks are synchronized on earth and one is then put in orbit, can the one in orbit somehow communicate information that it would allow calculating the time difference vs. the ground, without bringing the clocks together into the same reference?

Theoretically, how?



This is a question about theoretical empirical measurement, and whether general relativity prevents empirical measurement in this case; the question is not about calculating the orbital mechanics that would give you the satellite position and provide time to dilation calculated based on kinetics and gravity (ie, can time dilation be measured at a distance when spacetime curvature is unknown).
Theoretical example
If you have mirror clocks with one photon that counted ticks for each bounce between mirrors, and if the satellite and the earth ground station clocks are separated for long enough that the tick count differs substantially for the clock in space versus the clock on earth, then can the satellite simply send its tick count to the ground so that the tick values can be subtracted to estimate total time dilation? (Could tick counts then be streamed once per second to estimate "instantaneous" dilation?)
Is there some general relativity issue that prevents this communication because the ticks would be received on earth as being the same value? If so, how/why?
Other possible ways of asking the same question

Does communication itself between the different "gravity potentials" somehow offset what would be communicated, such that the time values communicated at a distance still result in equal values until they are brought into the same reference frame?

Is the communication of the rate of time passage between two reference frames affected by the dilation itself, such that the time measured ends up being the same when the communication reaches one side or the other?


(I am sure my terminology like "gravity potential" is incorrect, so please correct my terminology to reflect what is actually happening here in one way or the other.)

what is the point of this question? Is it "can you calculate the proper time on a world line in curved spacetime and compare it to a different worldline?" Then: the answer is "yes". and then: so what?

@JEB, updated post to address the comment.

Few remarks.. first about: "Could tick counts then be streamed once per second to estimate "instantaneous" dilation?" -- there's no "instantaneous" in GR/SR when you discuss two frames that are in relative motion. The satellite's "now" is different than Earth's "now" anyway (even Earth itself has no global "now", for that matter, but that's for most purposes a negligible effect). Second, I think the answer to your question may change depending on the type of the orbit... if it is circular the delay due to the path taken by a periodic beacon may be ignored (not 100% sure though).

@Amit, this would be empirical, so I realize that there is error in the measurement and transmission latency, but are you saying that clock tick counts can not (for some GR/SR reason) be sent from the satellite, or that their value would be "wrong" somehow when recieved on earth? If so, how wrong?  Please detail this in an answer.

@KJ7LNW I was pointing out that the ground "now" will be different from the satellite's "now". Simultaneity is a frame dependent property. But if you just want to measure time dilation experienced by a distant body, I think that's probably possible. What you can't do is to ensure that a relatively moving clock is always synchronous with your own. That's the meaning of time dilation. It's not that clocks just go abruptly out of sync somehow. The rate of passage of time is different between the frames. So which is it that you're asking? To measure dilation, or to sync relatively moving clocks?

@Amit, the goal is to measure dilation over time in an unknown frame from earth. high precision clocks have become amazing; I was at the IMS 2023 conference and a vendor shared that they can tell the mass of a mountain by the time dilation it presents and thought it might be fun to experiment with high precision clocks.

When on a spacecraft in a roughly-circular orbit time goes slower in low orbits and faster in high orbits, since gravitational and kinematic time dilation are both at play. See this graph that brings me great joy to see:

There is no reason that a satellite, knowing its orbital velocity, the velocity of an observer on the ground due to Earth's rotation, and its altitude cannot calculate where it lies on this graph.
What you can do is know what time dilation you perceive relative to someone else in a different or even accelerated frame. What you can't do is synchronize clocks with that person, because you can't signal them before your time dilation changes to start their clocks.

That really is an amazing graph, I do not think I would have realized that kinematic time dilation exceeded gravitational time dilation in low orbits. Did you create graph? By all means keep the graph as part of the answer because it is awesome, but this does not quite answer my question (or it does and I did not understand how). I have updated the post for additional clarity, so please take a look.

Haha, thank you, no I didn't create that graph, it's on Wikimedia Commons. As for the question: if you're asking if it's possible for Clock A to know exactly how much time dilation there is between itself and Clock B (that seems to be what you're asking at the top, at least). You can know how much time dilation there is, you just can't synchronize those clocks, i.e. have them ticking at the same time in both frames).

@controlgroup I think OP's emphasis is on wanting to measure time dilation nonlocally and "directly", i.e. deduce the amount of time dilation from something like analyzing the signals received from a periodic beacon (periodic in the satellite's frame).

Well, if you account for light travel times, you can always get an arbitrarily-good approximation (in my eyes, just as good as the real thing). You just need to figure out the velocity and position of the thing you’re trying to measure and to have a knowledge of the spacetime thereunderlying.
